# What will be the official language of the Kingdom of Israel?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, hebrew, aramaic, yiddish, satmar

This question assumes the correctness of the Shita that it is forbidden to use Lashon Koidesh for mundane language today. Rather I'm asking if this will or will not be the case in the restored Kingdom of Israel.

I don't know if the Satmarer Rebbe specifically wrote on this or not, in Vayoel Moishe or some other Seifer.

But when the King-Moishiach comes and restores the Kingdom of Israel, will the Lashon Koidesh be restored as the language of day-to-day affairs, or will Yiddish remain?

(Edit)

*grammar

Some thoughts and possibilities:

1. The assumption being that it would be no longer required to abstain from speaking Lashon Koidesh in day-to-day affairs if in the time of Moishiach, Klal Yisroel would no longer say anything forbidden. Thereby Lashon Koidesh could be restored as a general language, and Yiddish et al. could be discarded.
2. The assumption being that it is not enough to merely abstain from speaking forbidden things when speaking Lashon Koidesh, and instead that it is forbidden to speak of any mundane thing at all when speaking Lashon Koidesh. Thereby with Lashon Koidesh being reserved only for holy affairs, if in the time of Moishiach, Klal Yisroel will no longer speak of day-to-day mundanities and only of Toirah, then Lashon Koidesh could be restored as a general language. If not then Yiddish et al. would remain in such a function.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135010/discussion-on-question-by-oliver-goransson-what-will-be-the-official-language-of).

Comment: My logic is the following: The Hebrews allegedly didn't "change their language" in Egypt. Assuming the Torah was given as it is now, in the times of Moses, the Hebrews spoke Biblical Torah for all purposes. This is "the baseline". If the establishment of the Halachic State is meant to "return the original greatness", Hebrew must be returned to be the State Language.

Comment: Two notes: a) speculatively when such State is established, the Messiah is present and we see no division b/w holy sacred and secular. b) the Shita you mention is "educational, and not Halachic, meaning it focuses on people's awareness to differentiate the holy and worldly, rather than real Halachah.

Comment: @AlBerko Some good points made here. Thanks for the contributions and insight.